# "to do good with change""

Tags: colloquial-language

> She doesn’t do good with change, so we try to keep the routine in the house to avoid boosting her anxiety.

It seems that “do good” is a synonym for “adapt/bear/accept” and the like. Can anyone confirm my understanding?

Is it colloquial? I have never met this phrase before.

Comment: You might never meet it again! Alternatives include *She doesn't do change* (implying she refuses to change, rather than that change doesn't suit her), and *She doesn't get on with change* (same as not doing good; change affects her badly). I'd advise you to accept those extremely slangy usages if you encounter than - but for yourself, stick with more literal phrasing, such as *She doesn't **like** change* or *Change **upsets / confuses / disturbs** her*.

Comment: Note that "do good" here is more ***literal***. It doesn't explicitly mean she doesn't *accept* change (though that my be a strong implication). It's that she ***doesn't thrive*** in a changing environment - in fact, worse than that, any changes made tend to actually cause her harm / distress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Colloquial. Because of the second part of the sentence...

> so we try to keep the routine in the house to avoid boosting her
> anxiety.

...I believe that 'do good with' in the first part is a very regional or dialect expression meaning 'deal well with', or 'cope well with'.